# Rename .json file node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to rename a `.json` file in `node.js` this file is dynamically generated and located in the folder `/export`. the file will always start with `contentful-export-XXX.json` The XXX could be different on the file, and have random numbers and letters in its place. It is not possible to know the full file name before hand. Therefore I would like to rename the file to `contentful-export.json` instead of `contentful-export-XXX.json`. I hope this is clear.

Therefore, I believe that I would need to get the file name from the folder `export` and then insert this into a `fs.rename()` but I am unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression (regex). I think this will match:

`/contentful-export-[a-z]*[A-Z]*[0-9]*.json/g`

So if you get a list of your files, and see which files matches this regex, you can rename it.

```
` fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
      if(item[i].match(/contentful-export-[a-z]*[A-Z]*[0-9]*.json/g){
         //do the rename
      }
    }
  }); `
```

I haven't test it, but should be something like that

Comment: Can you please provide an example of getting a list of the files and see if it matches.

Answer (score 0):

Could probably use `fs.readdir` to get the list of files inside of your `export` dir and then rename the file with `fs.rename`

ex.

```
fs.readdir('/export', function(error, list) {
    if (error) throw error;

    list.forEach(function(file) {
        if (file.includes('contentful-export-') {
            fs.rename('/export/' + file, '/export/contentful-export.json')
        })
    });
});
```